# How do i change the label's color in a BottomNavigationBarItem in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm putting some bottom navigation bar items in my app's menu and I want them to have some labels. I put the labels but I don't really know how to change their base color. Like I want all of them to be white.

Here's the code for one of them:

```
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF084A76),
      fixedColor: Colors.white,
      items: [
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                //Borramos un lote
                deleteLote();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 47,
                width: 50,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black38),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.delete,
                  size: 32,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            label: 'Borrar Lote'),
        BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: InkWell(
              onTap: () async {
                //Añadimos un lote
                addLote();
              },
              child: Container(
                height: 47,
                width: 50,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                    shape: BoxShape.circle, color: Colors.black38),
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 32,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            label: 'Añadir Lote')
      ],
    )
```

Image of how it's looking right now, for reference:

[image: BottomNavigationBarItems]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead use :

```
unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
```

you can try :

```
unselectedItemColor: Colors.white,
unselectedFontSize: 14,
```

in your BottomNavigationBar

Answer (score 10):

You have to change `unselectedItemColor` property in your `BottomNavigationBar`.

```dart
bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
      unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 14),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF084A76),
      fixedColor: Colors.white,
      unselectedItemColor: Colors.white, //<-- add this
...
```

More details: [BottomNavigationBar](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomNavigationBar-class.html)

Comment: I tried that, but didn't work. Maybe I'm putting something wrong there. I updated the question so all the BottomNavigationBar code can be seen.

Answer (score 3):

If the color for the label is still not seen, you can try this:

```
showUnselectedLabels: true,
```

in your BottomNavigationBar